# 12.10 extended desktop executed programs start

Tags: multiple-monitors

On 12.10 my extended desktop is just perfect! But i cant set where to start the executed programs. Their always start at the monitor, but i want to start at the laptop screen.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
On compiz-config-manager there is a windows placement option, where can enabled some function.